# Searching CSV with 1.6 Million lines (150MB) file?

Tags: performance, matlab, file-io, large-files, import-from-csv

I have a CSV containing 1.6 million lines of data and at around 150MB, it contains product data. I have another CSV containing 2000 lines, which contains a list of product in the big CSV. They relate to each other by a unique id. The idea is to add the product data in the CSV with 2000 lines.

The databank.csv has headers `ID`, `Product Name`, `Description`, `Price` .
The `sm_list.csv` has header `ID`.

The result is to output a csv with products in `sm_list.csv`, with the corresponding data in `databank.csv`... 2000 rows long.

My original solution reads in all of the `sm_list`, and reads databank line by line. It searches `sm_list` for the `ID` in the line read in from databank. This leads to 2000x1.6Million = 3200 million comparisons!

Could you please provide a basic algorithm outline to complete this task in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know to how read/write CSV files in MATLAB (several questions here on SO shows how), here is an example:

```
%# this would be read from "databank.csv"
prodID = (1:10)';     %'
prodName = cellstr( num2str(prodID, 'Product %02d') );
prodDesc = cellstr( num2str(prodID, 'Description %02d') );
prodPrice = rand(10,1)*100;
databank = [num2cell(prodID) prodName prodDesc num2cell(prodPrice)];

%# same for "sm_list.csv"
sm_list = [2;5;7;10];

%# find matching rows
idx = ismember(prodID,sm_list);
result = databank(idx,:)

%# ... export 'result' to CSV file ...
```

The result of the above example:

```
result = 
    [ 2]    'Product 02'    'Description 02'    [19.251]
    [ 5]    'Product 05'    'Description 05'    [14.651]
    [ 7]    'Product 07'    'Description 07'    [4.2652]
    [10]    'Product 10'    'Description 10'    [ 53.86]
```

Answer (score 1):

have to be using matlab? If you just input all that data into a database, it'll be easier. A simple `select tableA.ID, tableB.productname... where tableA.id = tableB.id` will do it.